# Restangular - get root collection

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to implement Restangular in my SPA application.
I have multiple API root addresses.

So I created base providers (factories) for each API root, for example:

```
function ApiUsers(Restangular){
    return Restangular.withConfig(function(config) {
        config.setBaseUrl('/srv/users');
    });
}
```

Where /srv/users returns all users.
So my question is - how i can query root? I mean, I want to do something like:

```
return ApiUsers.getList();
```

or

```
return ApiUsers.all().getList();
```

But nothing seems to work... :(

Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **app.config.js**:

```
'use strict';

var appConfig = function (RestangularProvider) {

  var serverID = 'http://domain.com'; // sample 

  // Set default api
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(serverID + '/srv/users');

};

appConfig.$inject = [
  'RestangularProvider'
];
```

**users.api.js**:

```
return Restangular.all('').getList();
```

Comment: The `one()` function has a second argument that accepts an id e.g. `.one('users', 1)`.  `one('users', 1).get()`translates to `/users/1`

Comment: I know about `.one()`. I just want to declare root configuration for each API root. So i want `UserAPI` to be root, without wrappers. Coz I can do with base URL `/srv/` something like `Restangular.all('users')`, but I want to hide base collection in base URL, so I can call users like `UsersAPI.all()`, to translate it in `/srv/users`

Comment: My wrong, see my updated, if it not help you, pls tell me to delete it :)

Comment: Strange! :D I was pretty sure, that I've tried this... It worked. Thx! ;)